# Avoid expanding linked objects when serialising

Tags: c#, .net, json, json.net

I am using JSON.NET to serialize some c# objects into JSON (and then write to a file).

My two main classes are:

```
public class Reservoir {
    private Well[] mWells;

    public Well[] wells {
        get { return mWells; }
        set { mWells = value; }
    }
}
```

and

```
public Well() {
    private string mWellName;
    private double mY;
    private double mX;

    public string wellName {
        get { return mWellName; }
        set { mWellName = value; }
    }


    public double y {
        get { return mY; }
        set { mY = value; }
    }

    public double x {
        get { return mX; }
        set { mX = value; }
    }

    private Well[] mWellCorrelations;
}
```

The problem is that the output looks like:

```
'{"wells":[{"wellName":"B-B10","y":217.04646503367468,"x":469.5776343820333,"wellCorrelations":[{"wellName":"B-B12","y":152.71005958395972,"x":459.02158140110026,"wellCorrelations":[{"wellName":"B-B13","y":475.0,"x":495.14804408905263,"wellCorrelations":[{"wellName":"B-B11","y":25.0,"x":50.0,"wellCorrelations":[]}
```

i.e. the associated wells of each well object are expanded as objects themselves and this becomes a serious problem of space and time when there lots of associated objects.

I suppose I would have preferred something like:

```
'{"wells":[{"wellName":"B-B10","y":217.04646503367468,"x":469.5776343820333,"wellCorrelations":[{"wellName":"B-B12"}], {"wellName":"B-B11","y":217.04646503367468,"x":469.5776343820333,"wellCorrelations":[{"wellName":"B-B13"}
```

i.e maintaining only the well name as the link (assume its unique).

Is there a way to do this with JSON.NET?

You have set

```
serializer.ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

but it doesn't make any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a new readonly property called WellCorrelations that only got the names of the well correlations, and slap a `JsonIngore` attribute on your mWellCorrelations, like so:

```
[JsonIgnore]
private Well[] mWellCorrelations;

public string[] WellCorrelations 
{ 
    get { return mWellCorrelations.Select(w => w.wellName).ToArray(); }
}
```

http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/ReducingSerializedJSONSize.htm

That way, the serializer will only serialize the names of the correlated wells.

Comment: Thanks, i understand the rational but how do i populate the values to the JSON object? Do i add the Well object (by having another property (public Well[] wellCorrelationsWells) or the wellNames only? If the latter, how do I do this?

Comment: If you add the property I suggested to your Well class and serialize it using JSON.NET, it should serialize that property as

    "wellCorrelations":["B-B12"]